# Find $c$ in $2x^5 + 64 = \int_c^x g(t) \,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, parametric

> Let $g(x)$ be a continuous function for any $x \in R$ that satisfies:
>
> $$2x^5 + 64 = \int_c^x g(t) \,dt$$
>
> Find the value of $c$ or prove it does not exist.
>
> ---

I suppose the starting point is the following:

$$2(x^5 + 2^5) = \int_c^x g(t) \,dt$$
$$x^5 = \frac{\int_c^x g(t) \,dt}{2} - 2^5$$
$$x^5 = \frac{G(x) - G(c)}{2} - 2^5$$

But what should follow afterwards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well put $x=c$ in your equation, which will give $\int_c^{c} g(t)dt = 0$. You will simply get $-2c^5 = 64 \iff c = -2$.

Comment: Hahah I was mistaken anyway. The term $2x^5$ cancels out on both sides of the equation, leaving your answer: $c = -2$. You are correct :)

Comment: @user yes i understand, nevermind!

Answer (score 4):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have 
\begin{align*}
(2x^{5}+64)'=g(x),
\end{align*}
then $g(x)=10x^{4}$. Substituting back to the expression we get 
\begin{align*}
2x^{5}+64=\int_{c}^{x}10t^{4}dt=2t^{5}\bigg|_{t=c}^{t=x}=2x^{5}-2c^{5},
\end{align*}
so $c^{5}=-32$ and hence $c=-2$.